# How to make sure ImageButton background and layout background color are the same

Tags: android

I set my activity main layout's android background to #FFFFFF, and my image buttons' background to @android:color/white, to make the background of the imagebutton seem transparent as it's the same color of my layout.

However after I ran my lint test, it told me I'm overdrawing, painting regions more than once.

From what I understand, what is happening is android is drawing over my set #FFFFFF background making it redundant, correct? Well then what should I do to make my image buttons match the color of the background? I'm not seeing where android studio is retrieving the color it's using as the root background color, so I can't change it to be @android:color/white like my buttons, and I'm not 100% sure what color android is painting over my layouts with, so I can't change my image buttons to that color either. I heard it's #FAFAFA, is that known for Android Studio 3.6?

Comment: Try `@android:color/transparent` instead of `@android:color/white`.

Comment: @Tigger Thanks! So that did work to match the image button background and layout background. Now I do prefer that both be pure white instead of the whitish gray that Android Studio uses, is there a way I can make both of them use #FFFFFF? I read online that it can be unstable and the color won't work on some phones... Is that true? If not, then how can I use full white instead?

Comment: Well, now that the imagebutton background is transparent, you can set your activity's background color to whichever color you want. You can also declare your own version of "transparent" in your colors resources as #00000000 to prevent OEMs from messing up your colors.